# How to run integration tests from packages?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test

I have a project where my structure is like this:

```
my_project/
  features/
    feat1/
      integration_test/
        ...
    feat2/
      integration_test/
        ...
    ...
  lib/
    integration_test/
      ...
    ...
```

I have an issue with running integration tests from the features directory. Features are packages I made for my project. When I try to run a test from any of my features I got this error:

```
package:flutter_tools/src/test/integration_test_device.dart 52:7  IntegrationTestTestDevice.start

TestDeviceException(No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.)
```

If I run a test from integration_test from the main lib directory everything works well.

Is there a way of running the tests from the features directory?

Comment: From the doc https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/main/packages/integration_test#package-structure
I don't know if it's possible or a good practice to separate your folders like you do.

Comment: From the integration test view, I agree with you. But I need to keep this structure because of the complexity of the project.